# Side bar menu is disappearing when switching activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know that this question is asked a lot, but none of the answers worked for me.

I have two activities, `MainActivity` and `ShopActivity`. In `MainActivity` I have a side bar menu.

The issue happen when I switch activity, the menu disappear.

So how can I make the side bar menu fixed in each activity? Isn't this possible?

**Main Activity onCreate Method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    CreateExampleList();
    BuildRecyclerView();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Here's where I'm switching activities:

```
public void BuildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new ShopAdapter(shops);
    adapter.setOnShopClickListener(new ShopAdapter.OnShopClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            ShopItem selectedShop = shops.get(position);
            Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShopActivity.class);
            startActivity(k);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Shop: " + selectedShop.getShopName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Second Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
    mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_shop, null, false);
    mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);
}
```

Anyone know what's the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simply to initialize the menu bar the same way we did in `MainActivity` in each other `Activity`.

So simply write the code of `MainActivity` in the Second Activity.

**Second Activity onCreate Method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    CreateExampleList();
    BuildRecyclerView();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
}
```